# Xcode 9.3 hangs while Installing Components - Anti-Virus the culprit?

Tags: ios, xcode, installation

While reinstalling Xcode 9.3 (that's another story!) "Installing Components" stopped half way along the blue progress bar.

After disabling my anti-virus (Bit Defender) the installation resumed. Was this a coincidence? Has anyone had a similar experience while installing additional components?

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I disabled autopilot and everything worked as expected. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Was Bitdefender for me too! Hanging for an hour - turned off Bitdefender auto pilot and completed straightaway.